# I cannot access any website other than google by writing its IP address in my web browser

Tags: dns, nslookup

As an initial learner of Computer Networks I am exploring **nslookup** command. When I paste IP address of [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) given to me by my DNS server (which is 8.8.8.8 google DNS) it open the Google's page but no other website opens through its IP address being pasted in the address bar even if I write http/https or port number.

**Example** /networkengineering.stackexchange.com has following IP Addresses: 151.101.193.69, 151.101.1.69, 151.101.129.69, 151.101.65.69
But when I paste them individually in my chrome browser it gives **following error**:

"Fastly error: unknown domain: 151.101.65.69. Please check that this domain has been added to a service.

Details: cache-qpg1233-QPG"

Comment: Thanks found my answer over here
https://www.quora.com/Why-cant-all-websites-be-accessed-by-an-IP-address-alone

Comment: Glad you got good answers. they look to cover many of the individual reasons you might be having problems (SNI/multi-site hosting, HTTPS, geo-located hosting,  in-line infrastructure like load balancers, reverse proxies, ALGs, firewalls, etc ). All of these little semi-related things are converging in such a way that a FQDN is just plain required. Keep in mind, The Internet is an IP internetwork, but the WWW is a distributed application framework that sits atop it. by connecting with IP, you have satisfied the needs of the internetwork, but neglect the needs of the WWW components in play.